# Which one of the following subsets of $\Bbb R$ (with the usual metric)is NOT complete?

Tags: metric-spaces

I am stuck on the following problem that says:

> Which one of the following subsets of $\Bbb R$ (with the usual metric)is **NOT** complete ?
>
> 1. $[1,2] \cup [3,4]$
> 2. $[0,\infty)$
> 3. $[0,1]$
> 4. $\{0\} \cup \{\frac 1n : n \in \Bbb N \}$

### MY ATTEMPTS:

What I know is that [the unit interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_interval) is a complete metric space. So, option 3 can be eliminated. We also know that  a set then is [compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space) if and only if it is closed and bounded. Since [closed interval](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClosedInterval.html) is a closed set,it must be compact. Also since we know  [Every compact metric space is complete, though complete spaces need not be compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space),so the set given in option 1 is complete. Option 4 can be eliminated as the limit point of the set given in option 4 belongs to it. So, the answer should be option 2.

Am I going in the right direction? Is there any better ways to approach the problem. Feel free to comment. Thanks in advance for your time and regards to all.

Comment: Since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, a subset is complete if and only if it is closed. All four sets you have given are complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is misleading: **all** of the sets are complete. (1), (3), and (4) are compact and therefore complete. As for (2), any Cauchy sequence in (2) is bounded and therefore a Cauchy sequence in some compact interval $[0,a]$, so it converges. (Alternatively, you can use the fact that every closed subset of a complete metric space is complete, and $\Bbb R$ is complete.)

Comment: Sir,I will be obliged if you explain a bit the line "As for (2), any Cauchy sequence in (2) is bounded.... " in your answer.Thanks and regards for the nice explanation.

Comment: @learner: Every Cauchy sequence in any metric space is bounded. Let $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a Cauchy sequence in the metric space $\langle X,d\rangle$. There is an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $d(x_k,x_n)<1$ for all $k,n\ge m$. Thus, $d(x_m,x_n)<1$ for all $n\ge m$. Let $$r=\max\{1,d(x_m,x_0),d(x_m,x_1),\ldots,d(x_m,x_{m-1})\}\;;$$ then $d(x_m,x_n)\le r$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, so every term of the sequence is in the bounded set $\{x\in X:d(x_m,x)\le r\}$.

Comment: thanks a lot sir. It is clear now.

Comment: @learner: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I claim they are all complete subspaces of $\Bbb R$. You've shown $1$ and $3$ are complete. Option $4$ is compact as a closed subspace of $[0,1]$, and you already know compact metric spaces are complete. The only doubt left is for Option $2$. However, if we take any Cauchy sequence in $[0,\infty)$, it is bounded (why?) hence has a convergent subsequence by the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem. Now you can show that since the sequence is Cauchy, it converges to this limit point.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. But I am finding it hard to understand the line " However, if we take any Cauchy sequence in [0,∞), it is bounded (why?) ". Can you explain it ?

Comment: Maybe the easiest way to prove it is bounded is to suppose it isn't bounded. Then for every element of the sequence, there is something at least $1$ more than it. This shows the sequence can't be Cauchy, a contradiction.